# Grouping multiple controllers from same package in swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I am not able to find right way to group multiple apis in swagger.

Example:
1 have n number of Controllers.

let's say I have package
com.test.controller.feature1
com.test.controller.feature2

For both feature1 and feature2 I have x number of controllers.

Is there a way on the swagger-ui I can group these apis based on package so that swagger-ui is clutter free?

Here are the jars I am using for api documentation:

```
//springdoc-openapi
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with tags

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("XXXX")
@Tag(name = "PACKAGE name1", description = "Group 1") {}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("YYYYY")
@Tag(name = "PACKAGE name1", description = "Group 1") {}
```

These will be one group.

Check this: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/